# How to manage one to one relationship in mySql?

Tags: mysql

I've two tables one about Customers and the second one is about their Accounts as 'Customer_Account_Information'. we know that one customer can have only one account, so I'm trying to enforce one to one relationship, but i don't know the procedure/syntax in mySql or mySqlyog.
is there any one who can help me?

Comment: In my (design) experience, if you find two entities, that have distinct names (customer/account) and distinct roles (identity, accountability), then you should re-visit the assumption that these entities share an (enforcable) one to one relationship. You then have two options: join into one entity (as Chris McCauley pointed out) or implement to entities with business logic /warning code handling the 1 to 1 rule. Did you consider, that a customer might be a legal entity (company) with more than one person or departement (human) attached to it ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A simple implementation

This is not a perfect solution but it is easy to understand with a little bit of experience with mysql and referential integrity.

You need a [FOREIGN KEY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in customers to refer to customer_account_inforamtion. Since the account_id in customers is the only way to join the tables, no customer can have more than one record in customer_account_information.

In the sample definitions below, I've included a [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) which causes the customer to be deleted when their account information is deleted. You may or may not want/need this.

```
CREATE TABLE customer_account_information (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    some_attribute varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    another_attribute varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    account_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    surname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX account_id (account_id),
    CONSTRAINT account_id FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES customer_account_information (id) ON DELETE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The account_id in customers is the foreign key which refers to a record in customer_account_information

**Alternative implementation**

It might be an idea to revisit the design of the two tables. If each customer really can have only one account then perhaps all of the attributes of each can be merged into one table. Yes this business rule may change in the future but it would be a better idea to defer this work until really necessary - don't over engineer the solution today.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a **Foreign Key** contraint on table *Accounts* to table *Customers* using *CustomerID*.

Have a look at [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Also then make this a Unique Column in table *Accounts*

Have a look at [MySQL foreign keys - how to enforce one-to-one across tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113803/mysql-foreign-keys-how-to-enforce-one-to-one-across-tables)

You could also use the same *CustomerID* from table Customers as **PRIMARY KEY** column in table *Accounts* as **PRIMARY KEY**.